# ezxml is slow on Windows

Tags: c++, c, xml

my audio plugin uses ezxml on Windows and macOS. The function ezxml_toxml takes **3200 ms** to create XML test from a ezxml structure on Windows (Core i5-4460 3.2GHz).
On a MacBook Air (2014) with Core i5 1.4GHz it only takes **250 ms**!
On an M1 Mac it's even only **100 ms**.

The audio code runs about as fast on Windows as on macOS. So it's probably not a matter of compiler settings.
Xcode 12.5.1 builds for macOS, Visual Studio 2010/2022 for Windows.
Btw.: for both platforms EZXML_NOMMAP is defined.

I hope anybody can help me to improve the timing on Windows.

I tried all compiler switches in Visual Studio, even installed the current one.

For Windows I had to define:

```
#define snprintf _snprintf
```

and _snprintf is not 100% compatible. So I thought this might be the source of the bad timing and replaced it with a hopefully comptible function:

```
int mysnprintf ( char * s, size_t n, const char * format, ... )
{
    int iRet;
    va_list args; 
    va_start(args, format);
    iRet = _snprintf(s, n, format, args);
    va_end(args);
    s[n - 1] = 0;
    return iRet;
}
```

but this also didn't change the speed of execution.

Comment: C and C++ are two *very* different languages. Please pick the one you're actually program in (I'm *guessing* C?).

Comment: On an unrelated note, `snprintf` will *always* terminate the string it creates. You don't need to do that yourself.

Comment: Oh, and Microsoft support [`snprintf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/snprintf-snprintf-snprintf-l-snwprintf-snwprintf-l?view=msvc-170), no need for the non-portable `_snprintf`.

Comment: Are you building in Release mode? I have seen cases where unoptimized debug programs took 100 times as long as release with the same code and data.

Comment: @Some programmer dude
ezxml is in C, most of the other code is C++.
snprintf terminates automatically, _snprintf doesn't.
And maybe I'm simply missing a setting to enable the support of snprintf - but when I try to build without the #define I get a LNK2019

Comment: @drescherjm
thanks, but of course this was the first thing I checked ;-)

Comment: sorry, @Some programmer dude: now I see that snprintf is supported in current versions of Visual Studio. I had to define it in VS2010.

Answer (score 0):

solved: it's been the function realloc which has a bad performance on Windows.
A simple solution to enhance the performance is to increase the value of EZXML_BUFSIZE, so realloc will be called less often. But this will still be quite slow.

If you can estimate the resulting string size you'll get from ezxml_toxml quite well (like in my case) just give the variable max in ezxml_toxml this size so the first malloc will get all the memory needed. And so realloc won't be called.